# Añadir un tiempo de delay en swing

Tags: java, java-swing, hilos, timer

Basicamente mi programa es un juego de memoria basado en colores. esta funcion se encargaria de mostrar la secuencia de colores que fue saliendo.

Lo que quiero es agregar un delay adentro del for porque si lo ejecuto de esa manera, me muestra todos los colores al mismo tiempo, en vez de un color a la vez como quiero. Gracias por su tiempo!

/**
     * Intento de  funcion que me repita la secuencia de colores que ya 
     * aparecio. coloreando cada boton en el orden que aparecio
     * El ERROR es que no puedo poner un delay entre que me coloree un boton
     * y luego el siguiente. Me los marca todos al mismo tiempo
     */

```
public void repetirSecuencia(){

    Timer timer=new Timer(1000,null);
    timer.addActionListener((e)->{
        for(int i=0;i<respuesta.size();i++){
            <-delay aqui->
            int pos=Integer.parseInt(respuesta.get(i));
            generarColor(pos);

        }

        timer.stop();

    });
    timer.start();
}
```

Comment: y porque no utilizas un timer para llamar a generarColor indicando un delay y diciendo que no se repita? Sería algo así: Timer timer = new Timer(tiempoDeDelay, generarColor(pos));
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();

Comment: Voy a probar eso muchas gracias, no voy a tener problema con que la variable pos va cambiando? osea pos toma el valor de cada indice del arraylist.

Comment: no, no deberías tener problemas por pasarle un pos distinto en cada iteración.

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo por qué usas el ActionListener dentro del bucle pero una opción para ir añadiendo un delay, o retraso, con Java es mediante una llamada al método `Thread.sleep`:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

int pos = Integer.parseInt(respuesta.get(i)); 
generarColor(pos);
System.out.println("Otro color " + pos);
```

Comment: Descarta el action listener, lo que yo quiero hacer es que dentro del bucle, la accion tenga un delay despues de que se ejecuta. Osea por cada vez que se ejecuta mi funcion generarColor(pos); que tenda un delay para que no me muestre todos juntos. Pero trabajando con swing no funciona el Thread.sleep solamente me tilda ejecucion del programa y me muestra la ultima accion.